# Razor exception wrong line number in form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Why is .NET identifying the incorrect line number when an exception occurs inside form tags? Here is a simple test case in a Razor .cshtml file:

```
@{
    string[] test = new string[2];
    test[0] = "stuff";
}
@test[0] <br />

<form action="~music/addToCart" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="@test[2]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array" displays the line with `test[0]` when the actual exception is `test[2]`. The debugger also shows the incorrect line. It seems that when an exception occurs inside form tags the statement above the form is incorrectly identified as the location of the error. I have tried using the Html helper `BeginForm()` and got similar behavior.

Using Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2117.0. Visual Studio Community 2017.

Comment: There are two lines with `test[0]`. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @test[0] is incorrectly shown as the error. Sorry that my question was not clear.

Comment: This is an unfortunate side effect of the `cshtml` file being compiled to a `c#` class file which has a slightly different structure/layout than the `.cshtml` file

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce this. I have a theory:

Consider the original code (with line numbers):

```
1  - @{
2  -     ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
3  - }
4  - 
5  - @{
6  -     string[] test = new string[2];
7  -     test[0] = "stuff";
8  - }
9  - @test[0] <br />
10 - 
11 - <form action="~music/addToCart" method="post">
12 -    <input type="text" name="test" value="@test[2]" />
13 -    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
14 - </form>
```

The debugger reports line 9 as having the error, but I think that is razor's line number. If we take out any plain text (non-razor):

```
1  - @{
2  -     ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
3  - }

4  - @{
5  -     string[] test = new string[2];
6  -     test[0] = "stuff";
7  - }
8  - @test[0] <br />

9  -    <input type="text" name="test" value="@test[2]" />
```

We see that the error occurs in line 9 within the Razor context.

I think the debugger receives error information with a razor line number and consumes it against the file layout line number.

Definitely a bug. You should report it if someone hasn't already.

Comment: When the problematic code is given a valid index inside the form tags and @test[2] is put below the closing form tag the debugger identifies the correct line. I think this contradicts your theory. However it is a better theory than anything I came up with.

Comment: @Apollo: You are correct. I tested this and when the error code is outside the form tag (before or after), it reports the correct line as the exception source. That would seem to indicate that it is the Razor processing of the form tag that throws off the debugger/reporting.